# Rx Scheduler options deprecated

Tags: c#, system.reactive, scheduler

I'm trying to get started with Reactive Extensions (Rx). Here's a little example I cooked up:

```
        var query = from number in Enumerable.Range(1, 20) select number;
        var obs = query.ToObservable(Scheduler.ThreadPool);

        obs.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

When I use `Scheduler.ThreadPool`, `Scheduler.NewThread`, etc, I get this warning:

> System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.ThreadPool' is obsolete: 'This property is no longer supported due to refactoring of the API surface and elimination of platform-specific dependencies. Consider using Scheduler.Default to obtain the platform's most appropriate pool-based scheduler. In order to access a specific pool-based scheduler, please add a reference to the System.Reactive.PlatformServices assembly for your target platform and use the appropriate scheduler in the System.Reactive.Concurrency namespace. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=260866 for more information.

If I follow the warning's instructions I still get the warning. What am I expected to use for the scheduler exactly, if I want to use the various options that used to be available via the `Scheduler` class?

Comment: Can you post the code where you've followed the instructions?

Comment: Not much to post... I already had the reference and the Scheduler class is indeed from System.Reactive.Concurrency. I didn't understand what other scheduler I need to use instead.

Comment: So you didn't change the code at all? Scheduler.ThreadPool is obsolete. If you're still trying to use it (regardless of what library you've imported) it's going to be obsolete. I'm looking for the correct methods...

Comment: Sorry. Wasn't trying to be rude. I've had this problem myself on several occasions. I don't have access to VS right now, but I'm wondering if using `ThreadPoolScheduler.Default` gives the same issue.

Comment: You mean Scheduler.Default? No, that one's okay. It's all the others that are deprecated.

Comment: There should be Default properties on the other Scheduler classes as well, unless that API has been changed.

Comment: You are right - it seems that I can use NewThreadScheduler.Default, TaskPoolScheduler.Default, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most Schedulers should come with a default instance. You should be able to use `NewThreadScheduler.Default`, `ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance`, etc.